# Can I initialize a union as a function argument in some clever way?

Tags: c++, initialization, unions

I'm looking for a bit of syntactic sugar that I'm not sure exists.  It's hard to describe, so I'll provide an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; // haters gonna hate

union MyUnion
{
    float f;
    unsigned int i;
    // more types
};

unsigned int someFunction(MyUnion m)
{
    return m.i;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 10;
    float f = 10.0;

    // this is the syntactic sugar I'm looking to emulate
    cout << someFunction(i) << endl; // automagically initializes unsigned int member
    cout << someFunction(f) << endl; // automagically initializes float member
    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware I can just define a bunch of overloads of my function, declare the union on the stack, initialize it, like such:

```
unsigned int someFunction(unsigned int i)
{
    return i; // this is the shortcut case
}

unsigned int someFunction(float f)
{
    MyUnion m = {f};
    return m.i;
}

// more overloads for more types
```

But I'm hoping there's a better way.  Is there?

Comment: The prize question (or Thatcher question?) is: How is the function going to know which union member is active?  You've made the function call uniform, but now it's also somewhat hard to use.

Comment: `MyUnion m = {f}; return m.i;` Undefined behavior. Accesses a field of the union that isn't the last one assigned to. Which is why @KerrekSB's question is important.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Since the compiler knows what type I'm passing to the function, it can simply check if there is a member of the union of a matching type.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I don't care that it's technically undefined.  The standard specifically says that unions are exactly as large as their largest enclosed type.  If I declare a union of many types of equal size, any assignment to the union over any type must necessarily consume the entire contents of the union.  So unless it's magically cramming bytes into nowhere and retrieving them at will, it is defined implicitly as long as the data types I use inside it are the same size.

Comment: @Wug: The union members are always all there. But you don't now which one is *active*. If your members are pointers, you may well be violating aliasing assumptions.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It doesn't matter which member of the union is active; as long as any assignment to a member of the union overwrites the entire contents of the union, all of the unions members will change to reflect the bitwise data of the object most recently stored in it. This change is necessarily deterministic for ALL assignments provided that all of the members are the same size. For any unique float in my example, there is a unique unsigned int (and a unique32 bit pointer type, etc). For this to be false, there would have to exist a 32 bit quantity that was bitwise-inequivalent to itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give the union some constructors:

```
union Jack
{
    int a;
    float f;

    Jack(int a_) : a(a_) { }
    Jack(float f_) : f(f_) { }
};

Jack pot(1);
Jack son(1.);

int main()
{
    someFunction(Jack(100));
    someFunction(100);        // same, implicit conversion
}
```

Comment: You may also want to make said constructors [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1y7x448.aspx), depending on the exact behaviour you want.

Comment: @XavierHolt: Sure, why not :-)

Comment: Yeah, explicit constructors would make this much less of a hastle.